# Recursive context nodes for xpath->query

Tags: php, xpath

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is replacing the content of the src-attributes of a bunch of img-nodes by the content of the corresponding data-src-nodes in a page like the following one.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="a">
         <img src="" data-src="myValue" />
         <img src="" data-src="myValue2" />
      </div>
      <img src="" data-src="myValue" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to do this by finding a common base node (in this case the img nodes in the div with id *a*) and based on that node

- the node containing the value to copy and#
- the node retrieving the value

Script

```
<?PHP
$html = '<html><body><div id="a"><img src="" data-src="myValue"/><img src="" data-src="myValue2"/></div><img src="" data-src="myValue"/></body></html>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$basenode = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('(//div[@id="a"])');

if ($entries->length > 0) $basenode = $entries->item(0);
if ($basenode) {
    $img = $xpath->query('//img', $basenode);
    foreach ($img as $curImg) {
        $from = $xpath->query('//@data-src', $curImg);
        $to = $xpath->query('//@src', $curImg);
        $to->item(0)->value = $from->item(0)->value;
    }
    echo $doc->saveXML();
}
?>
```

Expected output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="a">
         <img src="myValue" data-src="myValue" />
         <img src="myValue2" data-src="myValue2" />
      </div>
      <img src="" data-src="myValue" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Actual output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="a">
         <img src="myValue" data-src="myValue" />
         <img src="" data-src="myValue2" />
      </div>
      <img src="" data-src="myValue" />
   </body>
</html>
```

So, the line

```
$from = $xpath->query('//@data-src', $curImg);
```

seems to actually base its search on the root node and not the img-node selected before. How can I solve this?

(I know that a possible workaround would be to omit selecting the img-nodes explicitly and doing something like from='//div[@id="a"]/img/@data-src' and to='//div[@id="a"]/img/@src' but I'm a bit concerned, that I might end up copying values between attributes of different nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` at the beginning specifies an *absolute* location path (i.e, from the document root). Instead, you want to use a *relative* one (relative to the context node).

For example; `.//@data-src`, or `descendant::img/@data-src`, and so on.